# How can I check whether my meeting date time is conflicting with already scheduled date time list

Tags: c#, datetime

I have meeting date say 19/03/2022 7:am to 9 am.

I want to check if above schedule date time is conflicting with list of other event which has got start and end date time similar to above format.

I want to do this in c# can anyone help me with above requirement.

```cs
public class ScheduledEvent {
  public int EventId { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartDateTime {get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; } 
}
```

`List<ScheduledEvent>` Schedules - has list of already scheduled date times.

```
Bool checkdatetimeconflict(datetime startdatetime, datetime enddatetime)
{
  List<PlannedEvents> lstEvents;//already planned event are in this list
}
```

lstEvents has list of EventId, StartDateTime,EndDateTime as attributes in the classes

Comment: You could check if the provided date is between dates of other schedules. Please add your code

Comment: Addd code in the comment

Comment: Are you looking for [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to determine if a meeting exists in the specified time range. Checkout the following example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class PlannedEvent
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime {get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; } 
}

class Schedule
{
    public static bool MeetingConflictsWithOtherMeeting(List<PlannedEvent> plannedEvents, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime)
    {
        return plannedEvents.Any(e =>
        {
            var startsInOtherEvent = startDateTime >= e.StartDateTime && startDateTime <= e.EndDateTime;
            var endsInOtherEvent = endDateTime >= e.StartDateTime && endDateTime <= e.EndDateTime;

            return startsInOtherEvent || endsInOtherEvent;
        });
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var events = new List<PlannedEvent>() {
            new PlannedEvent { EventId = 1, StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 08:00"), EndDateTime =  DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 08:30") },
            new PlannedEvent { EventId = 1, StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 10:00"), EndDateTime =  DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 11:00") },
        };
    
        var meetingStart = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 08:31");
        var meetingEnd = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-01 10:04");
        
        var hasConflict = Schedule.MeetingConflictsWithOtherMeeting(events, meetingStart, meetingEnd);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Has conflict: " + hasConflict.ToString());
    }
}
```